# Type and sub-type dependent properties

Tags: typescript

A tricky TS challenge.

#### What It's About

Intersecting multiple discriminated union types together where there is a "type"-"sub-type" relationship.

#### The Question

Suppose one uses discriminated unions to have type-dependent properties (the allowed properties of an object depend on the value of one of the properties of the object). We will declare such a type, `A`:

```js
enum AType {
  FOO,
  BAR
}

type ATypeToPropsMap = {
  [AType.FOO]: { foo: string }
  [AType.BAR]: { bar: string }
}

type AUnion = {
  [K in AType]: { type: K } & ATypeToPropsMap[K]
}[AType]

type A<TAType extends AType = AType> = AUnion & { type: TAType }
```

In this case, `A` can only have `type` = `FOO` and the property `foo`, or `type` = `BAR` and the property `bar`. One can use this `A` type like so:

```js
const a1: AType = {
  type: AType.FOO,
  foo: "123" // <-- Allowed
}

const a2: AType = {
  type: AType.FOO,
  bar: "123" // <-- Not allowed, 
}

const a3: AType = {
  type: AType.BAR,
  bar: "123" // <-- Allowed, 
}
```

It's helpful to create a "helper" type that generalizes this discriminated union behavior:

```js
type TypeDependantBase<
  TType extends string|number,
  TMap extends { [k in TType]: any },
  TTypePropertyName extends string,
> = {
  [K in TType]: { [k in TTypePropertyName]: K } & TMap[K]
}[TType] & { [k in TTypePropertyName]: TType }
```

This means that we can now succinctly define A like so:

```js
type A<TAType extends AType = AType> = TypeDependantBase<TAType , {
  [AType.FOO]: { foo: string }
  [AType.BAR]: { bar: string }
}, "type">
```

We will create two new types, `AFoo` and `ABar`, that are also discriminated unions. Each of them are discriminated by their own new "sub-types", `AFooSubType` and `ABarSubType` respectively, each of which, as implied, pertain to each `AType` value:

```js
enum AFooSubType {
  WIZZ,
  BANG
}

enum ABarSubType {
  CRASH,
  WOOSH
}

type AFoo<TAFooSubType extends AFooSubType = AFooSubType> = TypeDependantBase<TAFooSubType, {
  [AFooSubType.WIZZ]: { wizz: string }
  [AFooSubType.BANG]: { bang: string }
}, "subType">

type ABar<TABarSubType extends ABarSubType = ABarSubType> = TypeDependantBase<TABarSubType, {
  [ABarSubType.CRASH]: { crash: string }
  [ABarSubType.WOOSH]: { woosh: string }
}, "subType">
```

With `A`, `AFoo`, and `ABar` defined, one can then specify a type that maps `AType` to either AFoo or ABar

```js
type ATypeToSubTypeMap = {
  [AType.FOO]: AFoo
  [AType.BAR]: ABar
}
```

And then, at last, one can create an intersection of `A` and `AFoo`/`ABar` like so:

```js
type AWithSubType<TAType extends AType = AType> = A<TAType> & ATypeToSubTypeMap[TAType]
```

Now, the goal with this type, is to be able to define an object with the following type constraints:

```js
const a: AWithSubType = {
  type: AType.FOO,
  foo: "123",      // <-- This is still forced to be "foo" just like before, because type = FOO
  subType: AFooSubType.WIZZ, // <-- This is forced to be AFooSubType because type = FOO
  wizz: "456" // <-- This is forced to be "wizz" and not "bang" because of the definition of AFoo
}
```

Unfortunately, and being the impetus for this question, is that this *doesn't work*! It doesn't force the `subType` property to be the correct type.

The ultimate question, is how does one do that? Thanks!

#### Update

As @jcalz showed, one can define all the type-sub-type mapping and props in one monolithic object to get the correct props enforcement:

```js
type ADataMapping = {
  type: {
    [AType.FOO]: {
      foo: string,
      subType: {
        [AFooSubType.BANG]: { bang: string },
        [AFooSubType.WIZZ]: { wizz: string }
      }
    },
    [AType.BAR]: {
      bar: string,
      subType: {
        [ABarSubType.CRASH]: { crash: string },
        [ABarSubType.WOOSH]: { woosh: string }
      }
    }
  }
}

type ToDiscrimUnion<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends unknown ? {
  [P in keyof T[K]]: (
    Omit<T, K> & Record<K, P> & T[K][P]
  ) extends infer O ? { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] } : never }[keyof T[K]
] : never

type AWithSubType = ToDiscrimUnion<ToDiscrimUnion<ADataMapping, "type">, "subType">
```

This answers the question, however it does come with the limitation of `AWithSubType` not having a generic which means one cannot *explicitly specify* the `AType` of an `AWithSubType`, i.e. `AWithSubType<TAType>`. This means one cannot do things like object spreading, for example:

```js
const aTemplate = { type: AType.FOO, foo: "123" }

const a = { ...aTemplate, foo: "not 123" } // <-- Fails as `aTemplate` could be anything, so "foo" is not recognised.
```

However this is out of scope, of course.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, meant to be AType.

Comment: I find it unfortunate that we have to carry around all these intersections in the example code, some of which seem to be redundant.  Your main issue seems to be that `AWithSubType<T>` does not *distribute* over unions in `T`, which can be remedied by rewriting it as a distributive conditional type, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQVJjN).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: An observation: If I were going to try to do what the example here shows I'd probably refactor to a single object structure that we turn into a discriminated union programmatically, like maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5ekdN).  I don't think this is exactly in scope for your question, though.

Comment: Thanks for your attention again @jcalz. Your first proposal works. I found out that one can add `& { subType: TASubType }` at the end of `AWithSubType` and achieve the exact same result. That does end up duplicating the specification of the "subType" property though.

Comment: I can see that your second proposal brute forces the problem, as you imply, with the single object structure. `ToDiscrimUnion` bamboozles me.

Regardless, both solutions are acceptable, so I will leave it up to you for which one you select :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `& {subType: TASubType}`?  I don't see a `TASubType` type parameter anywhere.

Comment: If one adds on another generic (`TASubType`) onto `AWithSubType` that forces the `subType` to be valid via a new mapping type that maps `AType` -> AFooSubType | ABarSubType, then one can add on `& { subType: TASubType }` on the end.

Anyway, after some further exploration, it turns out that one runs into some really weird tsc bugs with the first approach. Turns out that it works for 2 ATypes, but any more and it start to fail in very weird and random ways that I can't figure out. It starts to not understand the type-sub-type mapping.

The second approach seems to be the only one to work.

Comment: Unless you show me with a [mre], preferably in a TS Playground link, I can't really continue to delve into this (especially not in the comments).  The first approach answers the question as asked, so if it's not appropriate, you should [edit] the question to show the failed use case. Otherwise my inclination is to post that one since it requires the least changes to the code you wrote.

Comment: The only issue with the second approach seems to be it's lack of a generic on `AWithSubType`. Because of that, one can't object-spread it and add on properties, i.e.:

1. Declare "template a": `const aTemplate: AWithSubType = { type: AType.FOO, foo: "123" }`

2. Spread "template a" and modify the `foo` prop: `const a: AWithSubType = { ...aTemplate, foo: "not 123" }`. Point 2 fails because it doesn't know at the time of spreading what `aTemplate` is.

Comment: Again, it's really hard for me to understand what you're talking about from snippets of code in comments.  Either [edit] the question to have a [mre] of what you need to see, or post a playground link in the comments (you can use [tsplay.dev](//tsplay.dev) to shorten playground links here)

Comment: No worries @jcalz, I've updated the answer with your second approach as the solution, which sufficiently answers the question. I don't want to take up any more of your time. Thank you very much. Feel free to post your answer for the credit .

Comment: All right, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your original type

```
type AWithSubType<TAType extends AType = AType> = A<TAType> & ATypeToSubTypeMap[TAType]
```

is that it does not *distribute* across unions in `TAType`.  Presumably you want `AWithSubType<AType.FOO | AType.BAR>` to be equivalent to `AWithSubType<AType.FOO> | AWithSubType<AType.BAR>`.  But it isn't.  Intersecting `A<AType>` with `ATypeToSubTypeMap[AType]` is going to give you "cross-terms" in your union which allow things you don't want:

```
const bad: AWithSubType = {
  type: AType.FOO,
  foo: "123",
  subType: ABarSubType.CRASH,
  crash: "456"
} // no error
```

The easiest way to fix this is to explicitly turn it into a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) where `TAType` is the checked type:

```
type AWithSubType<TAType extends AType = AType> =
  TAType extends unknown ? (
    A<TAType> & ATypeToSubTypeMap[TAType]
  ) : never
```

This might look like a no-op: after all, `TAType` always extends [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).  But it serves the purpose of splitting `TAType` apart into union members *before* evaluating the intersection, and then putting the results of those into a new union.  And that fixes the problem:

```
const a: AWithSubType = {
  type: AType.FOO,
  foo: "123",
  subType: AFooSubType.WIZZ,
  wizz: "456"
} // okay

const bad: AWithSubType = {
  type: AType.FOO,
  foo: "123",
  subType: ABarSubType.CRASH,
  crash: "456"
} // error!
```

---

As mentioned though, this entire approach is complex and produces fairly hard to understand types.  The type `AWithSubType` here evaluates to:

```
type AWithSubTypeEquivalent = (
  { type: AType.FOO; } & { foo: string; } & 
  { type: AType.FOO; } & AFoo<AFooSubType>
) | (
  { type: AType.BAR; } & { bar: string; } & 
  { type: AType.BAR; } & ABar<ABarSubType>
)
```

which is redundant (multiple copies of the `type` property in there) as well as confusing.

Personally, in this situation, I'd back way up and try to express everything as a single data structure which could then be programmatically transformed into the right sort of discriminated union.  Something like this:

```
type ADataMapping = {
  type: {
    [AType.FOO]: {
      foo: string,
      subType: {
        [AFooSubType.BANG]: { bang: string },
        [AFooSubType.WIZZ]: { wizz: string }
      }
    },
    [AType.BAR]: {
      bar: string,
      subType: {
        [ABarSubType.CRASH]: { crash: string },
        [ABarSubType.WOOSH]: { woosh: string }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then we can automate the idea of "given an object type where one of the properties is itself a mapping from discriminant keys to value types, produce a discriminated union where this property name points to a single key, and the value type for that key is lifted up on level".  Maybe that's weird, but here is how it could implemented:

```
type ToDiscrimUnion<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends unknown ? {
  [P in keyof T[K]]: (
    Omit<T, K> & Record<K, P> & T[K][P]
  ) extends infer O ? { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] } : never }[keyof T[K]
] : never
```

And you can see it in action:

```
type FirstStep = ToDiscrimUnion<ADataMapping, "type">;

/*
type FirstStep = {
    type: AType.FOO;
    foo: string;
    subType: {
      [AFooSubType.BANG]: { bang: string; };
      [AFooSubType.WIZZ]: { wizz: string; };
    };
} | {
    type: AType.BAR;
    bar: string;
    subType: {
      [ABarSubType.CRASH]: { crash: string; };
      [ABarSubType.WOOSH]: { woosh: string; };
    };
}
*/
```

That makes a single discriminated union on the `type` discriminant, which can now be discriminated further on `subType`:

```
type AWithSubType = ToDiscrimUnion<FirstStep, "subType">

/* type AWithSubType = {
    type: AType.FOO;
    foo: string;
    subType: AFooSubType.WIZZ;
    wizz: string;
} | {
    type: AType.FOO;
    foo: string;
    subType: AFooSubType.BANG;
    bang: string;
} | {
    type: AType.BAR;
    bar: string;
    subType: ABarSubType.CRASH;
    crash: string;
} | {
    type: AType.BAR;
    bar: string;
    subType: ABarSubType.WOOSH;
    woosh: string;
} */
```

That's exactly the same type except it's fairly obvious from looking at it what the types mean.  If you want to make it generic there are undoubtedly ways of doing so, such as just performing [an `Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
type AWithSubTypeGen<T extends AType> = 
  Extract<AWithSubType, { type: T }>;

type AFoo = AWithSubTypeGen<AType.FOO>;
/* 
type AFoo = {
  type: AType.FOO;
  foo: string;
  subType: AFooSubType.WIZZ;
  wizz: string;
} | {
  type: AType.FOO;
  foo: string;
  subType: AFooSubType.BANG;
  bang: string;
} 
*/
```

Most of this is drifting pretty far from the scope of the question as asked, though, so I should stop now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Ek4QAylwMldKRIAOoASQAWtmSewVJiAOKzJbXbi8PiHahJlMGW3sADCqj4CYAEvniOmZO3Syr63x4yZ1YPE8mrniQXGx3W9dOTLWOobeQYNltdvtDscR0PFwYbWn2B5d+ODF4s7mnQB3WhYLCu-JBu2jhenlJ8Ys+vb0B+BwpaUMoDfCAIzLVUq2yEdqz3cpJx1CCa2A+oEJgiBl2NdczS3S0UOAg9BQ8aDgK8ZtWzbJ14GoI4AAtfwKAjcNnCBzx7ciGSQK9wigWj-Tdf9ESQEMgKY0CwIHDpTFQwFnEPYh7WYx0ghfBiOi9NR0gQvsJHA9NaF0ajUJHCdtUeXVkH1JcnEFPgjIMclhk1STgMmYVNT8ABuKN2HgWooiQEAlN0-TUIpQUViU1TfE7Z0IkEgBGAAmABmEMbUUAB6dKkBOABaHLeWo2gniK-1aAwFgwmoRBtlKEwkG+QSwhMEMkAAKy4PyMFocFkG+SqIBtb50A65BVWcXxBWEjolJPJjzxzPMkEy7K8oKkqSsq6ravqwxZquIaQBGno5wm1wbzvIIQwAFgAVgANha5bcvygRCuKp5NogGrdDqhqQ3OrAWr2GrgBMXRBKyWIWoOo6TBCUpqOQbYIBCJg9JqOo4fnLTvN88Gsm2QK9IMpCZLC3ozJ8GRoqay7EpS6KpopxjVNI9tosomjLtuh7ZiWrLQeuahLGoHRClIaA4EQJA1iKvIMi4XRaAANzEMsY0rVNBSiwVUhx5ZxNGVlbHsUKPUimQnVp3jH34uTPW9djfTop8lX7co+CqDGzcaGk6jc9jwqQbkHIksYrBNqYmhmCQ5jcryDfKDDTU3C0zn+Yz8VMolAw+Ctvl+QU+QcODTPFZlYX84AEU0aK6VZGU5S1LPCQDehouXWSjz9yVK-L6EpXRdlZU5Pp4h5YuBVcOYRTFdwmQHgwG+HpuFSuYp3cMWzYJMp5NWQyyjVXE0diwtOrX3Bt7Yt-x2OtnP6PNs9HcybIXf42vBPDSN1YrecQq7hePMusPwlljr-WMLN6xdzZh2QU3ZKC9nAZvecO4ZyZynC+EK+o9p2XqMnU+qdtwalwaIfCHpSHMSAdeW894bZ-gYpQtSn4nbfnfrMQCwFRLaQHNWKC2QQqlz3kRJiyERGHxXKINcKdzTEKgWQq+7h5HMVgRRKi3F2EenEWeBB7ZrxcR4g-V2n8hJcJ-igxyr4mLSUUfJKmt9sZP3fGkJS1Z9b8yQGAEAPV+BBRJqI7Ycs6AKyVqrJAJhVbUF5JqCxfjDIXx3i3MyB88GOCLvvIRSAuDAHBKDK8dQAD8SAAAUgpiA2QSWhHklipL8kqTHRQABKJAQRgAQEiQnJAPlgB+QCr44m2DFFB09DrVw1sQz01SpNYCM10E6IWtFAG3N7ohj5stEw4IQBCDLN0vyBMibBVJkM5mN8aYunislKZrgmaiFcQI4isCObqJ4tdFZayso-BFgAQjEuUWWsAMBbOQnE4CJR0oACoynHUMCCpiABRAAjlwFWmBODg2cKUqk7BujDJvu5cewxuj3zbvigYwwoXEBxScs8vhSXVKHCcLBwFIxYuaR8TFWLgi4ufmoOlhL6pv3ofQPlSAKVcupc4kVCFGXaNECyqkjSSjgvSgoYoxAJbkGlpmYAMBFamEoIrXV4MCAlA1skruozFB63AdGP+TLRGAIWSA4spZbWQNlWrVwjz4GsXceBNYIBdAgEmDAR8ZNXBBy7tfGllsGRiuJa8aKEgbkQDjZyo89rVKFiLF+WI78k2NEzfMy87EllCtdtPKFtcoV2JflG9gzshUFuICmtN6alEepIi2PR7FOYaPLdW9tHb7lzV0WxYInETD9qMXbRQs6tCCg-r81YJh-mUVoGAL2tR1Q2haJknqQgsYCHQkCJJ2TckmHyUgIpXc3BmAlAeo90x0gctcJQMAekd3B3skgVQEAfLUG2CcJoNozA-oENMO9DSJDNMyUwEIPwkCUGvcENwABFB9EBD3wwcZQdDooBitPaYhuYj74YQejiUUURGOkoMkLQagUQEz3AcEaVdRV12buqNuvgAag0huJF-AwEZPJgshTw8o9HGO6GY5sH2EaJUKRkJ5LFCb8gqapK2xRz4mHZtzT+IVpKNNYuPHM7w1DS20LokZqtxnx4fHrdyyVULG0Pzs8mmZ2mM2dtUb2551n4jucLZ2sd+ip2GJJYF2zrr2DKuXf0w5oi2NrroFxjGJwpNMZY5wkSP8JAQuhQl-xVxw1Uic0pygQXiBqdiFV54nmi3mYWnVstbm+YOaheV+xdWavCqhVpxrzFs11chgZtrsckAdaxV11II3BXjc0w1nz3a2x1b7RF14dmBhTbK4ptSqg5t+gW9cpbI7VJjpawY6zfM4slF2eDPpfBYUleObcymlqJDjMmWlfLWVnprXeqVcqzoqpfW2n9JqLV2qdW6r1FGJhqADR2sNY4hXxoyGmUxWZVjzsLI8f91660PoI62j9Ha-8kIw1R2NJAp1FBlteQ9fHq1CeA8+t9X6yB-q0KBjsEgYMIbfmhv+w6qOsb6SRijNGStajhPhspZBEh7sCsJkVwZXcusffYF9y5jNTuITmt61w63lm8wm8tT5COfmxIGcBIsnB1SnswRIuFdwqLwF0Iy57l8qVvYEPEUkdnwJDmBbbpi9vgCMpvoHsToqJO7XCPJvQe3aWCl60FgbTCgFBdayS9rr3U3veU2n85x32CZ7M0N0BQXRvXYm0qlVYtCDFCAA)